# How to reset MutableLiveData list to display new data when using setOnClickListner?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit2

So I have been trying for quite some time to add a search functionality for my app using TMDB API.
What I have managed to do so far is to be able to search for a movie only the first time, so here's the problem when I am trying to search for a movie for the second time it will keep showing me the old movie list from the first search results, never updating the list accordingly to the search.

For example, i searched for a spiderman movie, it will show me every movie that has the keyword spiderman in it, and then when i try to search again for a different movie with a different keyword it will keep showing me the results from spiderman search, so is there any way to reset `MutableLiveData` list on every `setOnClickListner`, so I ll be able to search and display new movies on every search?.

Thank you in advance.

Here are the classes:

```
public interface SearchMovieService {

    @GET("search/movie?api_key=&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false")
    Call<MovieResponse> getMoviesWithSearching(@Query("query") String query);
}
```

```
public class SearchAPIManager {

    Retrofit retrofit =
            new Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

    private final SearchMovieService searchMovieService = retrofit.create(SearchMovieService.class);

    public void getMoviesWithSearching(MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> moviesLiveData, String query){

        Call<MovieResponse> movieHTTPRequest = searchMovieService.getMoviesWithSearching(query);
        movieHTTPRequest.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                MovieResponse movieResponse = response.body();

                if (movieResponse != null) {

                    ArrayList<Movie> movies = movieResponse.getMovies();
                    moviesLiveData.postValue(movies);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.getMessage();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class SearchMovieViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<List<Genre>> genresNames = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> moviesSearching = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public SearchMovieViewModel() {

        GenreAPIManager genreManager = new GenreAPIManager();
        genreManager.getGenreNames(genresNames);

        SearchAPIManager searchManager = new SearchAPIManager();
        searchManager.getMoviesWithSearching(moviesSearching, Constants.MOVIE_SEARCH);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<Genre>> getGenresNames() {
        return genresNames;
    }
    public MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> getMoviesWithSearching() {
        return moviesSearching;
    }

}
```

```
public class SearchMovieFragment extends Fragment {

    SearchMovieAdapter adapter;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private ImageButton ibSearch;

    private RecyclerView rvMovieSearch;

    private SearchMovieViewModel searchMovieViewModel;

    public static SearchMovieFragment newInstance() {
        return new SearchMovieFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_movie_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        etSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        ibSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.ibSearch);
        rvMovieSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.rvMovieSearch);

        rvMovieSearch.setLayoutManager(new VegaLayoutManager());

        ibSearch.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (etSearch.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                etSearch.setError("Type Something");
                return;
            }

            Constants.MOVIE_SEARCH = etSearch.getText().toString();

            searchMovieViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchMovieViewModel.class);
            searchMovieViewModel.getMoviesWithSearching().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (movies -> {
                searchMovieViewModel.getGenresNames().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), genres -> {

                    adapter = new SearchMovieAdapter(movies, genres);
                    rvMovieSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
                    rvMovieSearch.scheduleLayoutAnimation();

                });
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the page number from the query so that you can get more data from the API

Here you return only `page=1` for every request

```
public interface SearchMovieService {

    @GET("search/movie?api_key=&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false")
    Call<MovieResponse> getMoviesWithSearching(@Query("query") String query);
}
```

But you can make the `page` as a query parameter

```
public interface SearchMovieService {

    @GET("search/movie?api_key=&language=en-US&include_adult=false")
    Call<MovieResponse> getMoviesWithSearching(@Query("query") String query, 
                                              (@Query("page") long page);
}
```

And apply that when you request the service in activity:

```
long page = 1;
Call<MovieResponse> movieHTTPRequest = searchMovieService.getMoviesWithSearching(query, page);
```

Now you can increment the `page` value whenever you want to get new list of data.

UPDATE:

> let's say i searched for a spiderman movie, it will show me every movie that has the keyword spiderman in it, and then when i try to search again for a different movie with a different keyword it will keep showing the results from spiderman search

The `MutableLiveData` didn't actually being triggered for the new query, so its data doesn't change, you need to enqueue the data again in order to make the `MutableLiveData` updates the underlying data that being observed.

Notice that the ViewModel constructor won't get called again whenever you make a new query, so you need to add `searchManager.getMoviesWithSearching()` to somewhere else.

To to that you need to add a method in the ViewModel that renew the search

```
public class SearchMovieViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<List<Genre>> genresNames = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> moviesSearching = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public SearchMovieViewModel() {

        GenreAPIManager genreManager = new GenreAPIManager();
        genreManager.getGenreNames(genresNames);

        SearchAPIManager searchManager = new SearchAPIManager();
        searchManager.getMoviesWithSearching(moviesSearching, Constants.MOVIE_SEARCH);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<Genre>> getGenresNames() {
        return genresNames;
    }
    public MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> getMoviesWithSearching() {
        return moviesSearching;
    }

    public void updateMoviesWithSearching() {
        searchManager.getMoviesWithSearching(moviesSearching, Constants.MOVIE_SEARCH);
    }

}
```

And then call `updateMoviesWithSearching()` whenever you want to update the list. also make sure that you update `Constants.MOVIE_SEARCH` with the query

And whenever you make a new query: call `updateMoviesWithSearching()`

```
    ibSearch.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        if (etSearch.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            etSearch.setError("Type Something");
            return;
        }

        Constants.MOVIE_SEARCH = etSearch.getText().toString();

        searchMovieViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchMovieViewModel.class);

       searchMovieViewModel.updateMoviesWithSearching();
        searchMovieViewModel.getMoviesWithSearching().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (movies -> {
            searchMovieViewModel.getGenresNames().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), genres -> {

                adapter = new SearchMovieAdapter(movies, genres);
                rvMovieSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
                rvMovieSearch.scheduleLayoutAnimation();

            });
        }));
    });
```

Comment: I have been trying to display a new data by searching for a movie, so every time a user searches for a new movie it will update the Query("query") and will display a new list of data.

Comment: When the user updates the query to get more data, just increment the `page` variable and request the service again with `movieHTTPRequest.enqueue()`

Comment: I want to display the first page but with a different search result when a user searching for different movies,

Comment: Oh I got you .. let me check it

Comment: Thank you, for example let's say i searched for a spiderman movie, it will show me every movie that has the keyword spiderman in it, and then when i try to search again for a different movie with a different keyword it will keep showing the results from spiderman search.

Comment: @KarenNikoghosyan please check updated answer